# Unable to fetch data from redux store after page reload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I successfully created a component called **market**(parent Component) that fetches data from my firestore database through a dispatched action as the component gets mounted to the screen, in order to have the contents of my database stored in my redux store. I now retrieved my data from the redux store and mapped them into child components called **CardItem** which when selected, takes the id of the selected item and passes it through routes parameters and also pushes me to the route called **User**. I now connect the User route to my redux store with the intention of pulling data from it and filtering the user selected using the passed id through the route parameter in order to set the state in the **componentDidMount()** lifecycle method. My logic was successful until I tried reloading the route which then made the data inside my redux store disappear (state returned undefined after the first reload).

Any insight about this is highly appreciated and is me pulling data from the redux store and filtering the user using the id passed through route parameters better than having to dispatch another action to the database and filtering afterward?

Below is both the market(parent Component) and the nested User(child Component)route.

market component

```
...

class market extends Component{

    componentDidMount = () => {
      this.props.fetch()
    //   console.log(this.props.data)
    };

    // state={
    // }
    userSelectHandler= (id)=> {
        this.props.history.push({pathname: '/user/'+ id})
    }

    render(){
        let list=null

        if(this.props.loading){
            list=(<Spinner/>)
        }

        if(this.props.data){
            list=(
                this.props.data.map((data)=>(
              <CardItem userSelect={()=>this.userSelectHandler(data.id)} key={data.id} data={data}/> ))
            )
        }

        return (
            <section>
            <SearchBar/>
            {list}

        </section>
        )
    }
}


const mapStateToProps= state=> {
    return{
        data: state.market.data,
        loading: state.ui.loading
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps= dispatch=>{
    return{
        fetch: ()=>dispatch(fetchData())
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(market)
```

User Component
    ...
    class User extends Component{

```
    componentDidMount= ()=>{
        let copyData= [...this.props.user]
        copyData= this.props.user.filter(user=> user.id === +this.props.match.params.id)
       console.log(copyData[0])
       this.setState({
           user: copyData[0]
       })
    }

   state={
       user:null
   }

   componentDidUpdate= ()=> {
       console.log('will update')
       console.log(this.props.user)
   }


    render(){

        let card = (<Spinner/>)
        if(this.state.user){
            card=(
                <article  className={classes.CardBox}>
            <aside className={classes.CardBox_profDetails}>
            <p>{this.state.user.name}</p>
            <p></p>
            </aside>

            <aside className={classes.CardBox_pricingDetails}>
            <p>{this.state.user.rate}/rmb</p>
            <p>{this.state.user.range}rmb</p>
            </aside>
        </article>
            )
        }

        return(
            <>
              {card}
            </>

        )
    }
}


const mapStateToProps= state => {
    return{
        user: state.market.data
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(User)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because you have routes in your app that have data dependencies on other routes which are mutually exclusive.

In other words this comes down to your application architecture whereby the logic of your application is in the wrong place or your routing structure should be changed

Broadly, you have two options as i see it.

1. Make `market` a top level route and both `user` and `cardItem` children of market. For example, using React Router v3, Your route structure might look similar to this:

```
<Route path="market" component={MarketContainer}>
   <Route path="user" component={UserContainer} />
   <Route path="card-item" component={CardItemContainer} />
</Route>
```

Your application routes would be nested as follows and rendered as `children` of the top level `market` route with access to the data it requests on `ComponentWillMount`

`/market/user`

`/market/card-items`

and your `MarketContainer` render method would render the `children` prop similar to:

```
render() {
    const { loading, children } = this.props;

    if (loading) {
      return <Spinner/>;
    }

    return (
        <section>
          <SearchBar/>
          {children} // your children would be able to access to data in the redux store and handle rendering themselves
        </section>
    );
}
```

2. Use a side effects library such as `redux-saga` to handle your application control flow but that's another consideration/question entirely

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you very much Mark for the deep insight. I will definitely look into the route structuring as it might be the reason for this problem. I am a bit new to the using routes but, i will try and dive deeper into the docs to see what i can get from it.

Comment: And will surely look into your recommendation on redux-saga.

Comment: I honestly didn't think the route structure would have any effect on the data that my user component was supposed to extract, seeing that it was connected explicitly to the redux store instead of having to pass it down as props from the parent route.